# My Products error when i call api/product?id=.. in my url undefined function laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

1. MY **API/ProductController**

this is controller for api:

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function all(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('id');

        if($id)
        {
            $product = Product::with('galleries')->find($id);
        }
    }
}
```

2. MY **Models\Product**

```
namespace App\Models;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable =[
        'name', 'type', 'description', 'price', 'slug', 'quantity'
    ];

    public function galleries(){
        return hasMany(ProductGallery::class, 'products_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: what does this have to do with java or mysql?

Comment: I think no but if u have experience like my problem u can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace `galleries()` in Product model  with given below. You missed this `$this->`:

```
public function galleries(){
    return $this->hasMany(ProductGallery::class, 'products_id');
}
```

Comment: Solved thxu mr @vinod

Comment: how do my API look neatly down